# How to implement an efficient filter using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of items(about 100 items), which are displayed in a list.
There is also a provision to apply a couple of filters. 
I'm using knockoutJS for data binding. The current implementation is like so :

```
var vmModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            self.items = ko.observableArray([])
            self.filter1 = ko.observable()
            self.filter2 = ko.observable()
            self.filter3 = ko.observable()
            self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function(){
                 var allItems = self.items()
                 if (self.filter1()) {
                     allItems = ko.utils.arrayFilter(allitems, 
                                    function(item) {return "some condition";})}
                 ...
                 Other filters
                 ...
                 }) // end of computed function
            })// end of vmModel
```

In My HTML

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
    <li data-bind="text: some data"></li>
</ul>
```

Whenever one of the filters change the whole filteredItems is recomputed. So when the user sets filter1 and then filter2, filter1 is applied for 100 items. Then, again filter1 and filter2 is applied for the 100 items. 
I wanted know if there is more efficient way to do apply the filters ? i.e  re-use previously filtered result ?

Comment: Seems you're underestimating the computing power of modern devices. The only real feature that can make things smoother - `rateLimit`-ing your `computed` (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html)

Comment: Instead of using `ko.utils.arrayFilter` for each filter you are better off having one for loop and then filtering each item based on your filters. This will mean that if multiple filters are applied then there will still be only one loop through all the items. As f_martinez said rateLimiting could also be used but it will mean that the filter wouldn't be applied immediately which is probably what you don't want.

Comment: @WayneEllery I think I'm doing the same thing.
The problem is when you apply the second filter, the same loop is called, which then applies the filter1 and filter2 to the vanila list items.

Answer (score 0):

KO just knows you're using multiple Observable values in your computed value, but it doesn't know why. I think you can't specify to apply specific part of your code for an observable change event.

The only way i see to do that (but i think it's ugly), is to store your value into a private variable (not observable, juste a standard JS Var). When the computed is called, you compare the new variable with the latest. If there are different, you apply the filter and store de new value on the private variable.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit,
Assume filteredList1 == items with filter1, then when I add another filter, filter2 to which I add the filter? filteredList1 or to original List Items ?
In both cases filteredList1 and filteredList2 will not be same.
Also comparing them item by item is not something I want.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Knockout Projections](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-projections)

It provides efficient map and filter functions:

> The key point of this library is that these transformations are done efficiently. Specifically, your callback function that performs the mapping is only called when strictly necessary (usually, that's only for newly-added items). When you add new items to the source data, we don't need to re-map the existing ones. When you reorder the source data, the output order is correspondingly changed without remapping anything.
>
> This efficiency might not matter much if you're just squaring numbers,
>   but when you are mapping complex nested graphs of custom objects, it
>   can be important to perform each mapping update with the minumum of
>   work.